# Remove Branch selector from a particular Acumatica Custom Screen

Tags: acumatica

I have added a custom screen (using AEF) and I would like to remove the Branch selector from this screen. This is because this particular screen would not contain any data specific to Branches and therefore there is no need to show the Branch Selector (which could be confusing to the user). Is there a way to hide the branch selector?

I am referring to the highlighted part included in the below screenshot.

[image: Branch Selector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, as the Branch selector is part of the main frame, not an Aspx page shown inside the main frame. There is the Branch selector on every screen in Acumatica, including preferences and inquiry pages and even reports. It might confuse users even more if you hide it exclusively on one particular screen - somebody could start thinking that something was wrong with that screen.